# Unpack object inside {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I was using an API endpoint which returned an iterator object, but with the latest change, now it returns it inside {}.

previous:

```
return iterator
```

Current

```
return {iterator}
```

How can I unpack it in my client code?

Will this work?

```
iterator1 = API_CALL
const iterator = Object.keys(iterator1)[0];
```

Comment: `const { iterator } = API_CALL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructure the value:

```
const { iterator } = API_CALL;
```

This is the same as:

```
const iterator = API_CALL.iterator;
```